# Print part of a webpage with CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a div with a table. I have tried to print the div using Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var prtContent = document.getElementById("printable");
        var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
        WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.outerHTML);
        WinPrint.document.close();
        WinPrint.focus();
        WinPrint.print();
        WinPrint.close();
    }
</script>
```

But when I print this div, the div is not printed with its CSS like `text-alignment`, table borders etc.

Comment: Why don't you use [@media print](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/) to hide everything that shouldn't be on the paper?

Comment: inline styles or classes referenced through external stylesheet?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating a new document, it will be displayed and printed independently, unaffected by any style sheets in the creating document. If you want to style it, you need to associate style sheets with the created document. At the simplest, if all your CSS code is in a single external file `mystyle.css`, it suffices to add a `link` element that refers to it, e.g. the following statement before the statement `WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.outerHTML)`:

```
WinPrint.document.write('<link rel=stylesheet href=mystyle.css>');
```